# Most used fish shell commands?

Tags: shell, fish

I would like to know what commands I run the most in my fish shell. Is there a way to extract this from history?

For comparison, here is [the same with bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312428/how-can-i-make-a-list-with-most-used-commands-in-terminal).

Comment: It seems the history file `~/.config/fish/fish_history` already removes duplicates? That would make this impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, fish doesn't track this information. Your history is ordered by MRU but it doesn't track the total use count.

Comment: Ok, I report it as [an issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2398) then. :)

Answer (score 6):

Until the [issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2398) you reported is resolved this seems to work kinda like the bash way. I would love to see this as an actual feature of Fish through with an option to the `history` command.

`history | awk '{print $1}' | sort  | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head -10`

```
517 git
314 drush
197 sudo
171 cd
115 man
103 echo
 95 vi
 81 dig
 67 set
 66 ls
```

I also posted this as a Fish & Bash answer over here https://askubuntu.com/a/717653/11929

Comment: That won't do what you want because fish eliminates duplicates in the history.

Comment: Ahh, I guess I had a different use case in mind. Which was just the actual command repetition, not the arguments too.